# How to parse two JSON in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm parsing a column from a table called "respuesta_api" which itself contains a JSON.

```
SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE(respuesta_api, '$.RESPONSECODE') AS RESPONSECODE ,
    JSON_VALUE(respuesta_api, '$.DICTAMEN') AS DICTAMEN ,
    JSON_VALUE(respuesta_api, '$.CEDULA') AS CEDULA ,
    JSON_VALUE(respuesta_api, '$.PAIS') AS PAIS ,
    JSON_QUERY(respuesta_api, '$.REGLAS') AS REGLAS ,
    JSON_VALUE(respuesta_api, '$.VERSION') AS VERSION ,
    fecha_respuesta AS FECHA_RESPUESTA,
    id_consulta AS ID_CONSULTA
FROM 
    TABLE_ORIGEN;
```

Output:

| RESPONSECODE | DICTAMEN | CEDULA | PAIS | REGLAS | VERSION | FECHA_RESPUESTA | ID_CONSULTA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OK | MALO | 1234 | EEUU | {"R20000A":0,"R20000B":0,"R20000C":2,"R20101A":19,"R20101B":19,"R20201A":19,"R20201B":19,"R20102":"DOMINICANA","R20202":"4","R20103":1,"R20203":0,"R20104":0,"R20204":0,"R20105A":0,"R20105B":0,"R20205A":0,"R20205B":0,"R20106A":0,"R20106B":0,"R20106C":0,"R20206A":0,"R20206B":0,"R20206C":0,"R20107A":0,"R20107B":0,"R20107C":0,"R20207A":0,"R20207B":0,"R20207C":0,"R20108A":0,"R20108B":0,"R20208A":0,"R20208B":0,"R20109A":true,"R20109B":true,"R20109C":true,"R20109D":true,"R20209A":true,"R20209B":true,"R20209C":true,"R20209D":true,"R30100":1000} | 916248E95C7CF82327773A44B2175A82 | 2022-06-09 | 2598 |
| OK | APROBADO | 5678 | EEUU | {"R10001":0,"R10002":1,"R10003":0,"R10004":0} | 7FFB3B9A1158E444FE373309BA41004C | 2022-06-09 | 7654 |

But in turn that JSON which I already parses, also has another JSON called "REGLAS" `(JSON_QUERY(respuesta_api, '$.REGLAS') AS REGLAS)` which I need to parse into new columns like this:

| RESPONSECODE | DICTAMEN | CEDULA | PAIS | R20000A | R20000B | R20000C | R20101A | R...n | R10001 | R10002 | R10003 | R10004 | AVERSION | FECHA_RESPUESTA | ID_CONSULTA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OK | MALO | 1234 | EEUU | 0 | 0 | 2 | 19 | n | null | null | null | null | 916248E95C7CF82327773A44B2175A82 | 2022-06-09 | 2598 |
| OK | APROBADO | 5678 | EEUU | null | null | null | null | nulln | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7FFB3B9A1158E444FE373309BA41004C | 2022-06-09 | 7654 |

I know it's super messy, but it's what I need.

Is it possible to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite near to answer.

As [`JSON_QUERY()` extracts an object or an array from a JSON string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), and use `JSON_VALUE` to extract value from the JSON object.

```sql
JSON_VALUE(JSON_QUERY(respuesta_api, '$.REGLAS'), '$.R20000A')
```

While this can be simplified as:

```sql
JSON_VALUE(respuesta_api, '$.REGLAS.R20000A')
```

with the [JSON Path expressions (Refer to the table)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#lax-mode-and-strict-mode).

[Sample DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb045a44b2845fa2a9bc6c3e573138ec)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this would be much easier with `OPENJSON`.

You can get a whole object such as `REGLAS` by using `nvarchar(max) AS JSON`, then feed it into the next `OPENJSON` using `CROSS APPLY`

```sql
SELECT
  j1.RESPONSECODE,
  j1.DICTAMEN,
  j1.CEDULA,
  j1.PAIS,
  j1.VERSION,
  j2.*,
  o.FECHA_RESPUESTA,
  o.ID_CONSULTA
FROM TABLE_ORIGEN o
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(o.respuesta_api)
  WITH (
    RESPONSECODE varchar(10),
    DICTAMEN varchar(100),
    CEDULA int,
    PAIS varchar(100),
    REGLAS nvarchar(max) AS JSON,
    VERSION varchar(100)
  ) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.REGLAS)
  WITH (
    R20000A int,
    R20000B int,
    R20000C int,
    R20101A int,
    R10001 int,
    R10002 int,
    R10003 int,
    R10004 int
  ) j2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1485c/4/0)